# Copying the database from SQL Server to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I currently have SQL Server 2005 and I want to make a copy of the entire database into PostgreSQL. I don't want to migrate to new PostgreSQL but just a entire copy. I almost have more than 1 TB of data in SQL Server. Is there any tool that can simplify this copying process? Also, I assume compression techniques have become much more advance in recent years so how much storage I should expect in PostgreSQL?

Comment: if you have Sql Server, you can use the data migration wizard included with Integration Services.

Comment: Can I make rough estimation of the memory size that I need in PostGreSql for 1 TB of MS SQL 2005 data?

Comment: Is that 1TB for just the database or does that include transaction logs?

Comment: 1 TB is just for the database without transaction logs. Also, I should correct my mistake. It is from MS SQL 2000 not 2005 from where I want to copy the database.

Answer (score 2):

For the person who's done this before I've looked at many tools and there are many pitfalls in doing that.  The cheapest way I found to do this was to do a text dump, convert, and load.

My setup was MSSQL 2005 to PostgreSQL 8.x on Linux.  The reason I say convert is because in the bulk `bcp` dump there is no way to distinguish between `''` and `NULL` so the `COPY` command I used to load was complaining about `NULL` value for a table that had `''` as a part of the primary key.

Dumping the schema also required conversion since the types are not exactly compatible, so it's been a bit of work but no buying of data migration tools which can be [expensive](http://www.swissql.com/products/datamigration/store.html) for what may be just one time use.

There are other tools like [this one](http://dbconvert.com/convert-mssql-to-postgre-pro.php?DB=6) but from what I have tested(2 years ago) has limitations.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Corrected.  Force of habit.

Comment: Postgres certainly treats `''` as an empty string. **Oracle** treats an empty string as `NULL`. Are you sure this wan't your migration tool that changed that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was actually writing the scripts myself.  When I was trying to do a bulk import into PostgreSQL it was complaining that I couldn't do that because `NULL` cannot be part of the primary key.  Bulk import by default interpreted this as `NULL`

Comment: so it's a problem of that "bulk import" you were using. If that was the `COPY` command you can tell it to not treat `''` as a `NULL` value. If it was some other tool, you will need to check that tool's manual. Postgres can definitely use `''` as a value for a not-null column.

Comment: For me I had to as in the text dump there is no way to distinguish between the `''` and what `NULL` comes out to be.  Thankfully for me the table this happened in was deprecated.

Comment: that's one of the disadvantages of the "text format". You cannot distinguish between empty strings and nulls in there. But that does not mean that **PostgreSQL** cannot distinguish between them in the database. Please change your answer accordingly, because as it is, it's simply wrong.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name corrected.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for 2020** Use the [PostreSQL Migration Toolkit](https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/p/edb-postgres-migration-toolkit).  This will map data types and maintain foreign keys.  The utility is free and created by the postgres maintainers, EnterpriseDB.

The command is a little different for MSSQL because you cannot use "dbo" as a postgres schema.  It should look like this:

```
                                                                                                
C:\Program Files (x86)\edb\mtk\bin                                                              
λ runMTK.bat -sourcedbtype sqlserver -targetdbtype postgresql -targetSchema public dbo          
Running EnterpriseDB Migration Toolkit (Build 53.0.1) ...                                       
Source database connectivity info...                                                            
conn =jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/circfilm                              
user =postgres                                                                                  
password=******                                                                                 
Target database connectivity info...                                                            
conn =jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/circfilm                                                 
user =postgres                                                                                  
password=******                                                                                 
Connecting with source SQL Server database server...                                            
Connected to Microsoft SQL Server, version '12.00.6372'                                         
Connecting with target Postgres database server...                                              
Connected to PostgreSQL, version '12.2'                                                         
Importing sql server schema dbo...                                                              
Creating Tables...                                                                              
Creating Table: films                                                                           
Created 1 tables.                                                                               
Loading Table Data in 8 MB batches...                                                           
Loading Table: films ...                                                                        
[films] Migrated 1808 rows.                                                                     
[films] Table Data Load Summary: Total Time(s): 0.332 Total Rows: 1808 Total Size(MB): 0.8710937
Data Load Summary: Total Time (sec): 0.454 Total Rows: 1808 Total Size(MB): 0.892               
                                                                                                
Schema dbo imported successfully.                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                
Migration process completed successfully.                                                       
                                                                                                
Migration logs have been saved to C:\Users\user\.enterprisedb\migration-toolkit\logs          
                                                                                                
******************** Migration Summary ********************                                     
Tables: 1 out of 1                                                                              
                                                                                                
Total objects: 1                                                                                
Successful count: 1                                                                             
Failed count: 0                                                                                 
Invalid count: 0                                                                                
                                                                                                
*************************************************************                                   
                                                                                                
C:\Program Files (x86)\edb\mtk\bin                                                              
λ
```

The drivers for both SQL Server and postgres should be copied here: `C:\Program Files\edb\mtk\lib`  Use the JTDS driver for SQL Server, not the JDBC driver you get from Microsoft.

**UPDATE**

If you want to use some of the more obscure options, they go after the runMTK.bat command, not at the end.  Otherwise the errors are non-descript.

`c:\Program Files\edb\mtk\bin>runMTK.bat -truncLoad -dataOnly -tables table_test -sourcedbtype sqlserver -targetdbtype postgresql -targetSchema public dbo`

Comment: "*Use the JTDS driver for SQL Server*" is a pretty bad advice. It hasn't been updated in over 8 years and I doubt it can connect to any modern SQL Server version (lacking e.g. implementation for current TLS/SSL protocols). The Microsoft JDBC driver is way better than the abandoned jTDS driver.

Comment: Shouldn’t matter as the OP is using SQL Server 2000

Comment: I agree that the JTDS driver is ancient and to be avoided but the EnterpriseDB Migration Toolkit doesnt work with the MS jdbc driver.  jtds did 400k rows in 20 seconds with postgres lower case and correct data types, to a cloud sql instance no less.  openquery with odbc was 45 minutes to do 25k rows.